# How to check if data exist in laravel

Tags: laravel, duplicates

I have a form where user can input city and submit 
I have made simple logic to avoid duplication of same city
I have input name = city and city migration which has column name and created_by_id and I have also used city with one to many relationship with rooms . My Model name for city is TotalCity . and input name is city
in my controller I have done this logic

```
class QuickController extends Controller 
{
    public function logic(Request $request)
    {
       if(TotalCity::where('name',$request->city)->exists())
       {
         $city = TotalCity::where('name',$request->city)->value('id');
       }
       else {
          $city = TotalCity::create(['name'=>$request->city']);
```

`          }
        }
    }

This code still not working and I have also used firstOrCreate method but it is also working

What I wanted to do is 
If enetered data exists I want to take its value 'id' or If can get all its also okkay and if not exists creates new one !!!

How to do it

Answer (score 1):

you can try or share your controller full code

```php
else{
 $city = new TotalCity;
 $city->name = $request->city;
 $city->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add validation to check if it is unique.

```
public function logic(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      city => 'required|unique:tableName.column',
   ]);

   $city = new TotalCity;
   $city->name = $request->city;
   $city->save();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**[firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)** function is what you need

In your case :

```
TotalCity::firstOrCreate([
  'name' => $request->city
]);
```